# drawing directed graph

Tags: graphs, tikz-pic

How can I draw an edge from `(ab)` to `($a^3$$b$)`?

I tried using `\Edge(ab)($a^3$$b$)` like I did for drawing an edge from (b) to (e) but the same method didn't work.

I think it has something to do with using dollar signs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\Vertex[x=-1 ,y=-1]{e}

\Vertex[x=1 ,y=1]{$a^2$}

\Vertex[x=-1,y=1]{a}

\Vertex[x=1 ,y=-1]{$a^3$}

\Vertex[x=-3 ,y=-3]{b}

\Vertex[x=3 ,y=3]{$a^2$$b$}

\Vertex[x=-3 ,y=3]{$a^3$$b$}

\Vertex[x=3 ,y=-3]{ab}

\Edge(e)(b)

\Edge(ab)($a^3$)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs sure, sorry its my first post, thanks for the comment

Comment: The answer is easily found in Tkz-graph documentation, page 21. You already have this document in your system: type `texdoc tkz-graph` from command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `\SetVertexMath` right after `\begin{tikzpicture}` you don't need to use `$` in the vertices. This should allow you to reference them as you would other vertices.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetVertexMath
\Vertex[x=-1 ,y=-1]{e}
\Vertex[x=1 ,y=1]{a^2}
\Vertex[x=-1,y=1]{a}
\Vertex[x=1 ,y=-1]{a^3}
\Vertex[x=-3 ,y=-3]{b}
\Vertex[x=3 ,y=3]{a^2b}
\Vertex[x=-3 ,y=3]{a^3b}
\Vertex[x=3 ,y=-3]{ab}
\Edge(e)(b)
\Edge(ab)(a^3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, when using math you don't need `$` around each variable. You can use `$` once to enter math mode, then once again to exit. So, rather than `$a^2$$b$`, you would have `$a^{2}b$`. The `{}` is to identify the argument in the exponent.

Comment: Ah amazing thanks for the reply and solution!